# SCP loop stops executing after some time

Tags: bash, scp

So I have these two versions of the same script. Both are attempting to copy my profile to all the servers on my infra ( about 5k ). The problem I am having is that no matter which version I use, I always get the process stuck somewhere around 300 servers. It does not matter if I do it sequentially or in parallel, both version fail and both at a random server. I dont get any error message (Yes I know Im redirecting error messages to null now), it simply stops executing after reaching a random point close to 300 servers and it just lingers there doing nothing.

The best run I could get did it for about 357 servers.

Probably there is some detail I unknow that is causing this. Could someone advise?

### Sequential

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "$(date) - Process started"
all_count="$( cat all_servers.txt | wc -l )"
while read server
do
    scp -B -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" ./.bash_profile rouser@${server}:/home/rosuer/ && echo "$server - Done!" >> ./log.log || echo "$server - Failed!" >> ./log.log 

done <<< "$( cat all_servers.txt )"


echo "$(date) - Process completed!!"
```

### Parallel

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "$(date) - Process started"
all_count="$( cat all_servers.txt | wc -l )"
while read server
do
    scp -B -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" ./.bash_profile rouser@${server}:/home/rosuer/ && echo "$server - Done!" >> ./log.log || echo "$server - Failed!" >> ./log.log &

done <<< "$( cat all_servers.txt )"

wait

echo "$(date) - Process completed!!"
```

Comment: your while loop should be able to read your file list by using single redirection of input, i.e `while read server ; do .... ; done < all_servers.txt` . Your list is 1 server per line, and no spaces in server_name, right? Good luck.

Comment: run `ps` (e.g. `ps -C scp uww` on Linux) to find out which server it's `scp`ing to when it's stuck. then manually run `scp` to that server and see if it can succeed.

Comment: @shellter Yes, there are no problems with the naming.

Comment: @pynexj There is no specific server where its getting stuck. It get stuck randomly, and always around 300 servers. But no always on the same

Comment: Well please try `while ... done < all_servers.txt`. Your code of `<<< "$( cat allservers.txt)"` is likely blowing up because of a max-string size constraint for Here-Strings (`<<<`). Good luck.

Comment: It's possible that some instance of `scp` is reading from stdin, and thus bogarting the host list. Try `while read server <&3 ... done 3< all_servers.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with better input parsing.  Instead of parsing a bash herestring from a posix command substitution via a while read loop, I've got the while read loop running through your server list directly via pipeline (this assumes one server per line in that file. I can fix this if that's not the case).  If the contents of all_servers.txt was too long for a command line, you'd experience an error and/or premature termination.

I've also removed extraneous `./` items and I assume that rouser's home directory on each server is in fact `/home/rouser` (scp defaults to the home directory if given a relative path or no path at all).

### Sequential

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "$(date) - Process started"
all_count="$( cat all_servers.txt | wc -l )"

while read server
do
    scp -B -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" .bash_profile rouser@${server}: \
        && echo "$server - Done!" >> log.log \
        || echo "$server - Failed!" >> log.log 
done < all_servers.txt

echo "$(date) - Process completed!!"
```

### Parallel

For the Parallel solution, I've enclosed your conditional in parentheses just in case the pipeline was backgrounding the wrong process.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "$(date) - Process started"
all_count="$( cat all_servers.txt | wc -l )"

while read server
do
    (
        scp -B -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" .bash_profile rouser@${server}: \
          && echo "$server - Done!" >> log.log
          || echo "$server - Failed!" >> log.log
    ) &
done < all_servers.txt

wait

echo "$(date) - Process completed!!"
```

### SSH keys

I highly recommend learning more about SSH.  The `scp -B` flag was unknown to me because I'm used to using SSH keys and ssh-agent, which will make such connectivity seamless (use passwordless keys if you're running this in a cron job).

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much for your reply. But upon running it, im getting this error after some dozens of servers: './copy_profile_to_all_servers.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
./copy_profile_to_all_servers.sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable'

Comment: What is the value of `$all_count` and is this error solely in the Parallel solution?